# Perl going through a list of folders

Tags: perl

I have a folder named Logs, which contains several folders Run 1, Run 1 (1), Run 2 (2), etc. Each of these folder contains a plist file which I need to parse through. But I am not able to open the file. I am running the code below:

```
my $count = 0;
my $path  = "Logs/";

for my $file (glob("${path}*/*Results.plist")) {

    # initialize parser object and find insances of Fail
    my $xp      = XML::XPath->new(filename=>$file);
    my @nodeset = $xp->find('/dict/array/dict/string[1]');

    foreach my $element (@nodeset){

        if ($element->string_value == "Fail") {

            $count++;
        }
    }
}

print $count;
```

Edit: Now I need to look for "Fail" in the "string" child node. The plist file has 4 fails but my current code is returning only 2. Any ideas why?

The plist file has a structure smilar to this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>All Samples</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>LogType</key>
    <string>Fail</string>
    <key>Message</key>
    <string>Text</string>
    <key>Timestamp</key>
    <date>2012-10-17T08:01:51Z</date>
    <key>Type</key>
    <integer>4</integer>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>LogType</key>
    <string>Fail</string>
    <key>Message</key>
    <string>An error occurred while trying to run the script.</string>
    <key>Timestamp</key>
    <date>2012-10-17T08:20:46Z</date>
    <key>Type</key>
    <integer>7</integer>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>LogType</key>
    <string>Pass</string>
    <key>Message</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>Timestamp</key>
    <date>2012-10-17T08:01:51Z</date>
    <key>Type</key>
    <integer>5</integer>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: what do you want to do in the loop?  what have you tried to open the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
use strict; use warnings;
use XML::XPath;

my $path="Logs/";
my $count = 0;

for my $file (glob("${path}*/*Results.plist")){
    my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => $file);
    my $nodeset = $xp->find('/plist/dict/array/dict/string[1]/text()');

    foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
        $count++ if XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node) eq "Fail";
    }
}

print $count;
```

Comment: Thanks this works just fine! My code is still not running perfectly, just edited my question.

Comment: Provide examples if you need help.

Comment: I have added the structure of the plist file

Comment: You said _The plist file has 4 "fail"_, but the example have only one.

Comment: I have edited it, And the actual plist file is couple of hundred lines long so I am not posting it on here. But this should give you the idea of the structure of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a couple of issues:

1. the find() method returns XML::XPath::NodeSet object, not an array
2. your XPath expression is incorrect, it is missing "/plist" at the
3. begging you should use 'eq', not '==' to compare a string value of the element with "Fail" string

Here is how it should look:

```
my $nodeset = $xp->find('/plist/dict/array/dict/string[1]');
foreach my $element ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    if ($element->string_value eq "Fail") {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

PS: Also, I would suggest to use "use warnings; use strict;" in your code.

Comment: thanks for the corrections, I am still learning Perl. I already use strict and warnings. What is the difference between == and eq?